# How to use reactjs with magento 2?

Tags: magento2, javascript

I want to use `reactjs` in my magento 2 module for designing or developing PWA.

**edit:- how to integrate jqery with magento 2**

Answer (score 0):

you can use this magento module. This Simple module explains how to add and use React Components with Magento 2 and forgot about Knockout/JQuery Magento 2 UI

https://github.com/Genaker/reactmagento2

**Update:-**

Or you can use this code :-

```
// Include React JS itself 
<script src='https://npmcdn.com/react-dom@15.3.0/dist/react-dom.min.js'></script>
// Include Babel to avoid compilation 
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>

//Add to the page to render React component
<div id = "magentoReactApp"> </div>

//Write your scripts using babel 
<script type="text/babel">

var App = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return(
            <div className="App">
                 {/*Your React Magento UI Component code there */}
            </div>
        );
    }
});
ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('magentoReactApp')
);
</script>
```

for more details you can check this out
https://medium.com/@egorshytikov/how-to-use-react-js-with-magento-2-ed5e9f3cf9fe

Answer (score 0):

I would start with PWA studio, or a third party Magento 2 PWA that is built with React

- [PWA Studio](https://github.com/magento/pwa-studio)
- GraphCommerce ([demo](https://graphcommerce.vercel.app/))
- Deity Falcon ([demo](https://demo.deity.io/))